# Div hierarchy with initial height 100% to expand when content is loaded

Tags: html, css, frontend, height

I have an app like the following:

```html
<div class="app">
  App outer background
  <div class="navi">Navigation</div>
  <div class="content">
    App inner background
    <div class="search">Search and filters</div>
    <div class="list">
      Products List
      <div class="product">Product</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.app {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navi {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100%;
  
  background-color: darksalmon;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.search {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.list {
  min-height: 100%;
  
  background-color: green;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.product {
  height: 33vh;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

This is how it more or less looks like:

[image: How app looks like right now]

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/srutututu/3vznj46p/

I would like the "content" and "list" divs extend in height to 100% of the viewport (without adding a scroll) when content is loading and then extend as much as needed when content is loaded.

The current code allows the divs to extend after load but they are collapsed product list is empty.

The problem I have is once I set a min-height to 100% for the "app" div, chilren divs no longer can calculate their min-height based on that. Appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using vertical flex layouts. We have a vertical flex layout within `.app`, such that the child `.content` can `flex-grow` out any free space. Again, we do this for `.content`,  such that `.list` can `flex-grow` out any free space. When the products then load in, the elements expand as needed, since we only defined `min-height` as opposed to `height`.

Furthermore, we'd need to set a `min-height` of `calc(100% - 2rem)`. We subtract `2rem` for the amount of `padding-top` + amount of `padding-bottom`.

```js
document
  .querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
    target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="product">product</div>'.repeat(20));
  });
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: calc(100% - 2rem);
  height: fit-content;
  
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navi {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: darksalmon;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.search {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.list {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.product {
  height: 33vh;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  App outer background
  <div class="navi">Navigation</div>
  <div class="content">
    App inner background
    <div class="search">Search and filters</div>
    <div class="list">
      Products List
      <div class="product">Product</div>
      <button>Load products</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks! +1 for creative use of flexbox!